# MSBuild configuration in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am facing the error below during configuration of MSBuild in Jenkins:

> [ImageResize] $ cmd.exe /C " msbuild.exe p:Configuration=Release
>   E:\Heena\Applications\ImageResize\vbimage\ImageResize.sln " && exit
>   %%ERRORLEVEL%% 'msbuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file. Build step 'Build a
>   Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as
>   failure Finished: FAILURE

Please note that I have set MSBuild path up to msBuild.exe during setting up of MSbuild plugin. I have successfully deployed Visual Studio project on jenkins, but unable to configure it with MSBuild.

Answer (score 5):

1. In MSBuild installations option of jenkins,

   Choose the path to MSBuild = `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`
2. Then go to your respective jenkins project where you want to build,

   from,`Add Build Step` menu choose

   **Build Visual Studio Project or solution using MSBuild** option
3. `MSBuild version` will be what you defined in Step 1 and in `MSBuild File`

   type the path of your solution file and in `Command Line Arguments` option

   type `/p:Configuration=Release`.

Hope you got the answer what you were looking for.

Comment: Glad could help, if it's fine you can mark this answer as accepted so that it will help others

Answer (score 0):

A Guess from my side , msbuild.exe is not part of the **PATH** when you execute the msbuild command , check that before you run the command , try to export the the path to msbuild to the path variable.

Looking at the error i assume you are using windows/Batch , so try some thing like this before running msbuild

```
set PATH=%PATH%;path/to/msbuild/binary
```

Feel free to revert in case of any issues/concerns

Comment: Thank you so much, I have solved that error but after solving that I am facing an error as   "MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: C:\Users\ADMIN\.jenkins\workspace\ImageResize\ImageResize.sln "

Comment: Possible Reason for above error , space in the path , use quotes around the paths to avoid this error. or it can be due to your trying to build multiple projects which is not supported for your project , Try building a single project file [.proj] , please vote up my answer if it helped you , accept my answer if resolved your problem

Comment: well, I have already tried to put quotes around path but it not worked, even there is a single ImageResize.sln file. would you like to suggest me that, how choose MSBuild build file path in jenkins ?